# Textview changes background color for no reason

Tags: android, textview

I have two textviews in an activity, defined by xml - both with background color gray. In my app, I set one of the textviews background color to blue. This works as expected.

**BUT : When I turn the device (rotate), or leave the app and come back again, the other textview is also blue - same color as the one set intentionally...!?**

When I leave the app and start it again the second textview stays blue. When I stop the app from running (kill) and start it again the second textview is gray. But same problem appears as soon as I rotate the device or start the app the next time.

Problem device is running 4.1.1. - same app on 2.3.4 device runs with no problem.

SDK Tools 22.0.1, Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 32 bit
, Windows 7 64 bit

**EDIT :** Same problem on SDK Tools 14, Eclipse Indigo SR1 32 bit on Windows 7 32 bit

I have no idea what is going on there. It is some kind of undesired MAGIC. 
Could you please help me?

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Below is the real source code with no modification from the problem project.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv1.setBackgroundColor(0xff33b5e5);

    }

}
```

**acitivity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="TextView Test" >
        <activity android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2:** To make things even stranger: If I change color of textview2 slightly to i.e. #cdcdcd the problem does NOT come. It is only in case both colors (textview1 and textview2) are identical in XML.

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild of your project

Comment: I did that about 100 times already...! :-( The code above is an abstract from my real project. Making that abstract has cost me hours, while constantly refreshing and rebuilding in order to see if the problem is still there.

Comment: :( I can't see anything wrong with the code above, if you are getting the problem with the posted code that is really weird. Hopefully someone else will help.

Comment: I agree it is weird! Because it is 100% the above posted code.

Comment: So the problem is only on 1 device? Must be a problem with that device then. Try uninstalling the app fully then reinstalling. Anything odd about the device? On a stock ROM? etc. Can you test on other devices/emulators to confirm it's only on that device?

Comment: Completely uninstalled 100 times as well. No special ROM, not even rooted. Brand new Alcatel Idol. Nothing special about that device, except Dual SIM and stupid serial number 0123456789ABCDEF. :-) Tried on Google TV 4.2.2 -> no problem except rotating the monitor. Also on another device running 2.2.2 no problem. Even changed minSdkVersion and tried on a 240x320 ultra old 2.1 device: No problem. But I still do not think it is a device problem with the Alcatel. Maybe SDK or ADT or JAVA, or Eclipse is puzzled somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to that problem - although not an explanation. The problem only exists if initial colors of both textviews in xml are identical. The solution is therefore to give the textviews different colors.

So, if you have the same problem, this is what works for me:

**acitivity_main.xml: WITH Problem**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#cccccc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**acitivity_main.xml: WITHOUT Problem**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ffcccccc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#fecccccc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In other words I have used just a slightly different color (actually here it is different transparency) - and the problem is gone. I would not believe it if someone told me.

Answer (score 2):

Really this is wonderful :)
Try something like that-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv1.setBackgroundColor(0xff33b5e5);

       TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please correct the color... ccccccc is somewhat strange hex value... ;-) Just for anyone copying the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I stumbled on a similiar bug with android 4.1.1. After few hours of headache I found that when you declare colour to a element in XML and then later on edit it programmatically then something breaks. I managed to get rid of it by not declaring colour in xml for the element which I'll be changing background colour.